# How to fade in and fade out navbar based on scrolling position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a vertical navbar that I want to appear, and slowly fade in, when the user scrolls below the header. Likewise, I want the navbar to disappear, and slowly fade out, if the user scrolls onto the header. This is my current function:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollPos < 650) {
            $('.navbar').fadeOut(4000);
        } else {
            $('.navbar').fadeIn(4000);
        }
    });
```

The issue with this is that when I scroll below the header (or specifically a position of 650), the navbar quickly appears at full opacity, slowly fades out, then slowly fades back in. When I scroll onto the header, it just quickly disappears. How do I fix this to get the desired behavior?

Comment: Provide a Fiddle, I can't replicate your issue. My implementation of your problem https://jsfiddle.net/pstbq9w7/1/ and it works fine, could be caused by JQuery version. I have used 2.2.4 in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed it to use css transition and also added a slight debounce for the scroll event.  Stone the markup from @Adriani6 's fiddle, :P

```js
(function(){
  var timeout;
  var $window = $(window);
  var $navbar = $('.navbar');
  
  $window.on('scroll', function(e){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      if ($window.scrollTop() < 650) {
        $navbar.removeClass('hide');
      } else {
        $navbar.addClass('hide');
      }
    }, 100);
  });
}());
```

```css
body{
  height: 12000px;
}
.navbar{
  height: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  
  transition: opacity 4s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='navbar'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure to have `.navbar` hidden by default, giving it this CSS

```
.navbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Then it should fade in upon reaching that scroll position without that flash.